# android progress bar is accurate first time only

Tags: android-progressbar

The first time I run my progress bar for mobile android it works fine and the filling of the line is proportional to the time needed to fulfill my 'while...' code.  but all succeeding runs with same variables the bar fills up too fast.  I can't see any difference between the variables in the runs. 
/////code below

```
private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){

      @Override
      public void run() {



        while (myProgress <= secondsforbar)

        {
        try{
         myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
         Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Throwable t){
        }
       }
      }

      Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
       }
      };
        };

//******
```

Comment: is there some of kind of refreshing of the progessbar needed between executions?